# Wicket : pass json to ListView in java

Tags: java, json, listview, iterator, wicket

```
List userList = Arrays.asList(
            new User[] {
                new User("FirstA", "LastA"),
                new User("FirstB", "LastB"),
                new User("FirstC", "LastC")
              });


    add(new ListView("listview", userList) {
        protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
            User user = (User) item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("firstname", user.getFirstname()));
            item.add(new Label("lastname", user.getLastname()));
        }
    });
```

The above code adds values from List userList and displays Firstname and LastName in Table.

I need to pass JSONObject to ListView.

Json schema -

```
{"schema":[{"name":"John","id":"01"},{"name":"Sam","id":"02"}]}
```

Json is passed from Database -

```
JSONObject json=widget.getJsonForTableContent(query); //QUERY from Database
    json.toString();
    System.out.println(json);  //Prints json - {"schema":[{"name":"John","id":"01"},{"name":"Sam","id":"02"}]}
    Iterator<String> iter=json.keys();
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        String key = iter.next();
        System.out.println(key); //prints only "schema" from json in console
    }
```

The key value prints only "schema" in console.
How to parse and iterate json to print "name" and "id" also and pass these values to ListView to display in wicket Table

I am just a beginner.Any help would be appreciated.Thankyou

Comment: Assuming you're looking for the most efficient approach, recommend that  use a standard JSON parser API as in my answer below. If the goal is to learn how to parsing complex expressions then question/answer needs to be framed differently.

Answer (score 0):

Here is standard API for a [JSON parser](https://jsonp.java.net) / additional [overview with examples](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html)

The overview provides an example of using the API to parse JSON from an InputStream:

```
URL url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=java&type=post");
try (InputStream is = url.openStream();
      JsonParser parser = Json.createParser(is)) {
    while (parser.hasNext()) {
         Event e = parser.next();
         if (e == Event.KEY_NAME) {
             switch (parser.getString()) {
                case "name":
                    parser.next();
                    System.out.print(parser.getString());
                    System.out.print(": ");
                    break;
                case "message":
                    parser.next();
                    System.out.println(parser.getString());
                    System.out.println("---------");
                    break;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Not sure where you'll ultimately be deriving your JSON data from but if you wanted to test it with a static string you could convert the string to an input stream as follows:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

As for the ListView part of your question - it wouldn't be very difficult once you have parsed out the tokens to add them to the ListView similarly to what you've done.